# Create a query for special characters MINUS . and - in access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am using this Like "*[!A-Z0-9]*", to find special characters in mailing namelines however it picks up "." and "-" which I do not want to see

Comment: Could you provide more information about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Just to view mailing nameslines where there are special characters, not including a period or a dash or a space

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Like "*[!A-Z0-9.-]*"
```

If you want to check email addresses on validity, I'd suggest using VBA and Regular Expressions.
I guess there's plenty of posts on Stackoverflow regarding checking email addresses.
Otherwise have a look as this article on Geeksengine:

[How to validate email addresses](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/validate-email-vba.html)

Comment: I already tried this. I am not looking at emails. Just looking for where the string does not contain a special character other than a period or a dash.

Comment: Should work. If it doesn't work for you, then I have no clue why. Post your code/query plus specific data examples including actual and expected result..

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Temp_File.SFID, Temp_File.SFACCID, Temp_File.VIS_NUM, Temp_File.DEAR_LINE, Temp_File.NAMELINE1, Temp_File.NAMELINE2, Temp_File.SALUT, Temp_File.SFID, Temp_File.SFACCID, Temp_File.VIS_NUM, Temp_File.First, Temp_File.MIDDLE, Temp_File.Last, Temp_File.SUFFIX, Temp_File.SPO_VIS, Temp_File.SPOUSE_SALUT, Temp_File.SPOUSE_FIRST, Temp_File.SPOUSE_MIDDLE, Temp_File.SPOUSE_LAST, Temp_File.SPOUSE_SUFFIX
FROM Temp_File
WHERE (((Temp_File.NAMELINE2) Like "*[!A-Z0-9-.]*")) OR (((Temp_File.NAMELINE1) Like "*[!A-Z0-9-.]*"));